# Xcode/iOS xctest - Build input file cannot be found

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, xctest

I created the first unit test target in our `iOS` application by simply clicking through the plus icon inside the test tab on the left navigator.
(The target to be tested is set to the main application)

[image: Creating a new unit test target]

The unit test target created itself successfully but when I try to run the pre-generated tests, it outputs an error message. The error message displays that the build input file cannot be found. More specifically, the file `/Plugins/XXXTests.xctest/XXXTests` cannot be found. I double checked and in fact that file is not in that directory.

[image: Error message when trying to run tests]

While I could not find anything similar to this problem, I tried everything that was close to it but nothing seemed to fix problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This looks like some sort of issue with the build system. Try going into File -> Workspace Settings and changing the Build System.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a while but we finally found a solution! The problem was in the Podfile where our pods weren't being applied to the different targets of our app. To fix the solution we had to define a shared pod module that included all of our pods and then we applied this new module to each different targets in our app.

Our Podfile looks like this now[image: Shared pod example for multiple targets]

I hope this helps out some people!

Answer (score 3):

For me, it was because the test source files are not included in the test target.

Including those test files in the test target solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have it set properly in schemes?

Go to `Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme -> Test` and check, if your test target is properly added to the correct scheme. It should look something like this: 
[image]